# Search functionality on nodes of D3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

So I've generated a JSON file with four tiers and I used D3.js's collapsing boxes format (https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460) to create a visualization.

The problem I am encountering is that because the JSON file is so large, the visualization won't even load into the HTML and even when it does, the boxes in the visualization lag and don't collapse as they should.

Therefore, I want to create a search form using Select2's dropdown box in HTML, so that users can enter a node/tier 1 value and the visualization will appear with only that specific sector shown.  Since I am not good with Javascript I am finding quite hard to create such search functionality.  I have assigned ID numbers to each value in the JSON but I'm not sure how to approach it further (and if this is even the correct direction to go in).

Below is a sample of my JSON code.  So for example, if a user enters Lawyer and McDonald's, I want the visualization show only that node and it's children.  I apologize if I'm unclear but any help would be great.  Thanks so much!

`{
    "tree": {
        "name": "Top Level",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "[('Lawyer', 'McDonald's')]",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "[('Doctor', 'Wendy's')]",
                        "percentage": "10%",
                        "duration": 5,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "[('Nurse', 'NYU')]",
                                "percentage": "1%",
                                "duration": 5,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[('Pharmacist', 'LIU')]",
                                        "percentage": "4%",
                                        "duration": 5,
                                        "id": "1.1.1.1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "[('PA', 'Wagner')]",
                                        "percentage": "4%",
                                        "duration": 5,
                                        "id": "1.1.1.2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "id": "1.1.1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "[('Surgeon', 'Harvard')]",
                                "percentage": "1%",
                                "duration": 3,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[('Dentist', 'Buffalo')]",
                                        "percentage": "1%",
                                        "duration": 4,
                                        "id": "1.1.2.1"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "id": "1.1.2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "1.1"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "1"
            },
            {`

Comment: please share your sample json or some code that you tried.

Comment: @Ash thanks! Just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to change before you can actually make the D3 visualization work properly. Here are they.

**(1)** The data structure of the json doesn't match with the D3 code for displaying it. If you'd like to show the json data in the collapsing boxes properly adjust the below part of the code. *`d` here corresponds with your children object and has properties; name, percentage, and duration*

```
.append('xhtml').html(function(d) {
  return '<div style="width: '
    + (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px; height: '
    + (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px;" class="node-text wordwrap">'
    + '<b>' + d.name + '</b><br><br>'
    + '<b>Percentage: </b>' + d.percentage + '<br>'
    + '<b>Duration: </b>' + d.duration + '<br>'
    + '</div>';
});
```

**(2)** Your data doesn't contain the following which is responsible for displaying the arrows properly when collapsing items into a parent box. This might be the case why the animation is not as it should.

```
"link" : {
    "name" : "Link node 1 to 2.3",
    "nodeName" : "NODE NAME 2.3",
    "direction" : "ASYN"
},
```

**(3)** Here's the addition needed to implement the select2 drop-down box with all main branches.

**HTML**

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // map over all children in the main json branch
  var dropdownData = json.tree.children.map(function(branch, i) {
    return {
      id: i,
      text: branch.name,
    }
  });

  // Add all branches  to  select2.
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    data: dropdownData
  });

  // Add change event listener. When an option is selected, clear the SVG and run treeBoxes function again.
  $('.js-example-basic-single').change(function(e) {
    $("#tree-container").empty();
    var selectedBranch = e.target.value;
    treeBoxes(null, json.tree.children[selectedBranch]);
  });
});
```

Here's a live [working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/2gbrL7su/80) that still needs some tweaking but it'll help you in the right direction.

**NOTE:** To make this example work, I've added the json in the html document instead of loading data from a file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you.  Is there any way for me to change the Javascript to adjust to my current format of the JSON or must I change the format of my JSON in order for it to work?

Comment: Also, why is it that it works when it is added to HTML but when it is loaded from the file it doesn't?  I apologize if my questions are elementary, I'm quite new to coding haha!  Thank you in advance (:

Comment: No worries. To answer your first question. Yes, adjust your JavaScript code to the JSON structure if that's possible. Make sure you get to the right data. Perhaps [this part of a free course](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures) can help you to gain a better understanding of objects and how to get to the data.

Comment: It's hard to tell why the data from the file doesn't load. Do you get an error message. And what's the value returned when you load the json? Also, is the json file public as if that's the case I can tweak the example to include the json call.